# How To Set the name of a Service to something other than it's class name

Tags: android, service

How can I set the name displayed for a Service in android's list of running services? Is it possible to set a name of a service to something other than the class name of `Service Class`?

Comment: Um, where is this name supposed to be used or seen?

Comment: I want it to be displayed when use see list of services running.

Comment: My guess is that is driven by the `android:label` on the `<service>` element.

Comment: Ah, I think so. Let me try it.